# How do I display LF or CR (of both) characters, by their hex codes or Pilcrow signs, in MacVim?

Tags: macvim

I am using MacVim to open and edit a UTF8 file. Everything looks fine, but I need display line-feed and/or carriage-return characters. Both special symbols (as pilcrow signs) or hex codes would do.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Took me quite a time to find out you have to choose

**Edit** --> **File Settings** --> **Toggle List Mode**:

CR/LF characters are displayed as the $ sign.

(Who knows why 'Toggle List Mode'?)